# AWS Step Function is stuck at a state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to trigger a glue job with a state machine. When it triggers the job, after few seconds I can see from glue console that job is completed but in state machine it remain stuck at status in progress, I waited for 1 hour but it still remained at in progress status.
This is my state machine,

[image: State Machine Flow Diagram]

This is the code of the state machine,

```
{
  "StartAt": "Glue: Convert Raw to JSON",
  "States": {
    "Glue: Convert Raw to JSON": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "ConvertLandingToRaw",
        "Arguments": {
          "--bucket.$": "$.detail.requestParameters.bucketName",
          "--key.$": "$.detail.requestParameters.key"
        }
      },
      "Next": "Glue: Convert JSON to Parquet"
    },
    "Glue: Convert JSON to Parquet": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "ConvertJsonToParquet"
      },
      "End": true
    }
  },
  "Comment": "Re-partitioning the data and changing the data type."
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue. I have tried many links but could not get a satisfied answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case, I added this policy to the step functions IAM Role to make it work!

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "glue:StartJobRun",
                "glue:GetJobRun"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "YourGlueJobArn"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```